# Ksoap Object Serilisation error..Cannot serialize: [com.example.inventory.InventoryFilter@4138a178]

Tags: android, webservice-client, android-ksoap2

Is it possible to send array of complex objects to the server,I tried kvmSerializable interface , still get cannot serialise error during runtime.
The details and the error in logcat is as follows.

The part of the wsdl file I'm trying to access is as follows

```
<xs:complexType name="filterIPResources">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="tns:resourcePageDetails"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="resourcePageDetails">
<xs:complexContent><xs:extension base="tns:pageDetails">
<xs:sequence><xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"   name="inventoryFilterList" nillable="true" type="tns:inventoryFilter"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="inventoryFilter">
<xs:sequence><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="filterType" type="tns:filterType"/>  
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="filterValue" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="filterIPResourcesResponse">
<xs:sequence><xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:pageResult"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="pageDetails">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="blockSize" type="xs:int"/>
 <xs:element name="currentStartIndex" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The error in the logcat is as follows

```
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error  occured while executing doInBackground()
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: [com.example.inventory.InventoryFilter@4138a178]
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:687)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeProperty(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:671)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:640)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:683)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeProperty(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:671)
 01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):    at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:640)
 01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):    at  org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:624)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:681)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:597)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.write(SoapEnvelope.java:192)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.createRequestData(Transport.java:101)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:114)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:90)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at com.example.inventory.Search$ShowDialogAsyncTask2.doInBackground(Search.java:89)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at com.example.inventory.Search$ShowDialogAsyncTask2.doInBackground(Search.java:1)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-09 15:19:23.561: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     ... 5 more
```

The Asynctask which is used to consume the webservice is as follows

```
private class ShowDialogAsyncTask2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SoapObject> {

@Override
protected SoapObject doInBackground(String... urls) {

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME3);
   inventoryFilters = new ArrayList<InventoryFilter>();
    filter = new InventoryFilter();
    rpd = new ResourcePageDetails();
    Object[] deviceTypes = { DeviceType.HOST };
    filter.setProperty(0, FilterType.DEVICE_TYPE);
    filter.setProperty(1, deviceTypes);

    inventoryFilters.add(0, filter);
    rpd.setProperty(0, 1);
    rpd.setProperty(1, 15);
    rpd.setProperty(2, inventoryFilters);

    request.addProperty("arg0",rpd);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "resourcePageDetails", ResourcePageDetails.class);
    envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "InventoryFilter", InventoryFilter.class);
    envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Devicetype.HOST", DeviceType.class);
    envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "FilterType.DEVICE_TYPE", FilterType.class);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    androidTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL1);
     androidTransport.debug = true;

    try {
    androidTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION3, envelope);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    Log.d("xml", e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("MyAPP", "----------------- " + androidTransport.requestDump + "\n\n"
        + androidTransport.responseDump);

    return soap;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(SoapObject resultt) {
    super.onPostExecute(resultt);

}
}
```

I'm trying to solve this issue for the past 3 days...But no success at all. If Anyone know how to solve this please help me..

Comment: is your InventoryFilter implements serealizable interface???? Because When you want to serialize an object, that respective class should implement the **marker interface** `serializable`

Comment: @BBdev yes, in the server side the InventoryFilter implements serializable..Did u know SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement, writeObject etc means?

Comment: i didnt worked on KSOAP but you can see this link http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for posting the link,But I already referred that..but not found anything which helps to solve the issue

Comment: i think you should show some code too. May be some one can tell you what is the problem.

Comment: @BBdev i added the asynctask which i used to call the webservice

Comment: I am searching for this solution also

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 objects:  **filter = new InventoryFilter();** and **rpd = new ResourcePageDetails();**, then you need to  implements KvmSerializable interface from ksoap. You can use for your help these articles: 
[java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: MyClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148600/java-lang-runtimeexception-cannot-serialize-myclass)
and
http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/?p=2594